# NPM throws test error "jshint should pass for working directory"

Tags: node.js, jshint

I'm learning Node and currently in the middle of the following tutorial: http://mherman.org/blog/2016/09/25/node-passport-and-postgres/#.WRE8MonytZo

When I run `npm test` I'm getting the following error:

```
  1) jshint should pass for working directory:
     Error: Command failed: git log --pretty=format:%h --max-count=3
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

      at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:205:12)
      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
      at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:510:12)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

What's going on here? The above isn't pointing me in the right direction or yielding helpful search results.

Comment: have you tried to run `git init`? Looks like a Git repo is not initialized.

Comment: I just ran `git init` and the console returned `Initialized empty Git repository`... When I run npm test, I get the same error.